# How to distinguish scrolling by mouse from scrolling programmatically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events

I am scrolling an overflowing DIV's content by changing the `scrollLeft` property in Javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#scrollbox').scrollLeft($('#scrollbox').scrollLeft()+1);
}, 50);
```

However, I want to stop this as soon as the user scrolls the content themselves, using the mouse. I tried to detect this using the scroll event

```
$('#scrollbox').scroll(function(){...});
```

however, my automatic scrolling above also triggers that event. How can I distinguish this and only react to user-initiated scrolling? (or: how can I stop the above code from firing a scroll event? That would also do the trick)

Comment: Could you check if the users mouse is over the div being scrolled since most browsers only scroll div's when the user has clicked in the div. This wouldn't be full proof though, since your event could trigger when he is hovering over the div.

Comment: It's not practical since the DIV fills the whole client area. Moreover, Mac-users scroll with two fingers (without clicking).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover): function to stop the scrolling when the mouse is over the scrollbox element:

http://jsfiddle.net/bGHAH/1/

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(!mouseover)
    {
       $('#scrollbox').scrollLeft($('#scrollbox').scrollLeft()+1);
    }
}, 50);

var mouseover = false;
$('#scrollbox').hover(function(){
    mouseover = true;
},function(){
    mouseover = false;    
});
```

---

**Edit**

Based on your comments I managed to find a jquery plugin from the following site: [special scroll events for jquery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/).

This plugin contains an event which attempts to determine whether scrolling has stopped based on the period of time that has elapsed between the last scroll step and the time the check was made.

To get this to work I needed to slow your interval to just over the latency used by the plugin which worked out to be 310 milliseconds. Doing this meant I had to increase the scroll step to keep it visibly moving.

Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/EWACn/1/

and here is the code:

```
var stopAutoScroll = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){
    if(!stopAutoScroll)
    {
       $('#status').html('scrolling');
       $('#scrollbox').scrollLeft($('#scrollbox').scrollLeft()+10);
    }else{
       $('#status').html('not scrolling');
    }
}, 310);

$('#scrollbox').bind('scrollstart', function(e){
    stopAutoScroll = true;
});

$('#scrollbox').bind('scrollstop', function(e){
    stopAutoScroll = false;
});

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not practical because the DIV fills the whole client area, so the mouse is over it most of the time (without scrolling)

Comment: I ended up using a work-around (in the scroll event handler I save the last position and check if the scroll distance is 1px. If so, I assume it occurred from the programmatic scrolling, else from the mouse). But this is definitely a cool method, so I'll accept this answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For FF (Mozilla):

`document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', handler, false);`

For IE, Opera and Chrome:

`document.onmousewheel = handler;`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have an external flag that you can set prior to the programmatic scrolling, and then reset afterwords. If the scroll event is fired and this flag isn't set you know that the user is responsible and can act accordingly.

Unfortunately while this is browser independent and easy to read it could lead you to believe that some user scrolls are programmatic ones. However I would think the occurrences of this is small and may be worth it depending on the app you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Try [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel), for most modern browsers

> The wheel event is fired when a wheel button of a pointing device (usually a mouse) is rotated.