# How to detectpage scroll by dom engine in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Using  jQuery's `scroll()` function you can detect  *any scroll event*  whether it is created by whether user (i.e. mouse scroll, dragging the scroller) or DOM engine (add or remove element). How can I discriminate a scroll event fired by the DOM engine.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gd9a2/2/) clearly shows what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could handle this, but I don't know of one that's incredibly official.

One easy way is to just set a toggle when you initiate scrolling programmatically (such as setting a class) and removing it when you're done. I've [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nate/wHF8r/1/) to show how that would work.

```
$("#scrollable")
    .addClass('programatically-scrolling')
    .scrollTo({
        top: $("#scrollable").prop("scrollHeight") - $("#scrollable").innerHeight(),
        left: 0
    }, 1000, {
        axis: 'y',

        // Add a function to remove the toggle when the animation is complete
        onAfter: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('programatically-scrolling');
        }
    });

$("#scrollable").scroll(function (event) {

    // This will be true when your $.scrollTo animation is going
    // and false when you trigger the scroll with your mouse
    console.log($(this).hasClass('programatically-scrolling'));
});
```

There are other ways of tackling this, and other people who have [asked the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178863/how-to-distinguish-scrolling-by-mouse-from-scrolling-programmatically-in-javascr). Making a [jQuery special event](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/) would probably be the most fun, but the solution I outlined is probably the simplest.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light. I think I will use a jquery mouse wheel plugin such as http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs which seems the easiest solution for now. Therefore I'll make sure if user will use mouse wheel to scroll. Currently, I don't concern about scroller drag event.